# Selecting column with $ and [,] in R when using match -- updated packages, not working anymore?

Tags: r

I have a "dictionary" that has two columns: `suppliers` and `company`, meaning the parent company of the supplier.

I had a function that used a `match` between columns in a large dataset, finding the suppliers, and then returning the parent companies.

These columns included the first manufacturer, the second, etc, so my function took as input `column_to_transform`. For instance, I might wanted to transform `manufacturing_company` by translating `suppliers` into `company`.

The line of code worked like this:

`df_suppliers$company[match(df[,column_to_transform], df_suppliers$supplier)]`

So it would match the entries in `column_to_transform` to those in the `supplier` column of dataframe `df_suppliers`, and then access the `company` column in `df_suppliers`.

Yesterday I did an overall update of my R packages and now I find that the match always returns an `NA`. However, if I change to this (substituting `column_to_transform` for the relevant column name, e.g. `manufacturing_company`:

`df_suppliers$company[match(df$column_to_transform, df_suppliers$supplier)]`

So accessing the column through `$` rather than `[,column_name]`, it still works.

However, as I wanna pass this as an external column, using `df$column_to_transform` doesn't work. It returns `Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: column_to_transform`.

Any idea how I can make the "$" call select the column, or how I can transform `df[,column_to_transform]` into a character vector to do the matching?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I found out I can just use `df[[column_to_transform]]` and it works.

Comment: There should be no difference between the two options using a default `data.frame` - `var <- "mpg"; identical(mtcars[[var]], mtcars[,var])` - are you working with a 'tibble' or a 'data.frame'? Tibbles have `drop=FALSE` by default and won't return a vector when `var` is selecting 1 column.